# How to make Jersey 2 / Spring 4 load beans from @Configuration on a no web.xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs

For the sake of learning (Spring Boot is great and magic..), I am trying to set up a web app using Jersey and Spring (for DI). I have managed to get it working but only with Spring xml configuration.

I have extended ResourceConfig

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JerseyWebApp extends ResourceConfig {

  public JerseyWebApp() {
      packages("com.company.controller");
  }
}
```

My HelloController.java

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloController {

  private HelloService helloService;

  @Autowired
  public HelloController(HelloService helloService) {
      this.helloService = helloService;
  }

  @GET
  public String hello() {
      return helloService.sayHello();
  }
}
```

my HelloService.java

```
@Component
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class HelloService {

  public String sayHello() {
    return "hello from jersey webapp";
  }
}
```

and my spring applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company" />
</beans>
```

Also attaching my pom file

```
<properties>
    <jersey2.version>2.23.2</jersey2.version>
    <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>
                    jersey-container-servlet-core
                </artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring 4-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is it possible to get Jersey to load beans via a @Configuration class or shall I consider using Spring web/mvc to bootstrap the whole application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library `jersey-spring3` for "some reason" in the file `org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer.java` is by default looking for a classpath resource:

```
sc.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml");
```

and it does not support Java based Spring configurations. It is a known unsolved issue found [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2038).

So to register Java based annotation configurations with Spring DI I had to workaround it and bootstrap my web app using a custom implementation of `ServletContainerInitializer`.

**JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java**

```
public class JerseyServletContainerInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> classes, ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    //Register spring configurations
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext springContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    springContext.register(SpringConfig.class, JPAConfig.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(springContext));
    springContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

    //Register Jersey servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servletRegistration = servletContext.addServlet("JerseyServlet", new ServletContainer());
    servletRegistration.addMapping("/api/*");
    servletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servletRegistration.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", JerseyResourceConfig.class.getName());
  }
}
```

**JerseyResourceConfig.java**

```
public class JerseyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

  public JerseyResourceConfig() {
    packages("com.company.controller");
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice work around : Here's mine : https://github.com/bric3/jersey2-spring4-example